# Android app to write to a file every 5 ms

Tags: android, file

I have an android app that needs to store critical information coming from a sensor. The sensor updates data every 5 ms. I need to persist each of these data points on internal memory in text files.

In the current scenario, I am collecting data points for 2 seconds in memory and then writing to the file at the end of 2 seconds to save battery life. However, under situations where the app crashes, I am loosing the critical data points.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this?

Is it a good idea to write the data point to the file every 5ms. Would this significantly reduce the battery life and increase the load on the CPU? If anyone has come across a similar situation, can you please share how you resolved the issue?

Comment: Collect data at every 5ms and store to local db. Because writing on file will cost you a lot at every 5ms. And for writing to file, make it 1 day interval.

Comment: Not being sarcastic, but if you are working with critical information then your app cannot crash! In addition, you will be losing much more data during the crash, then during the 2 seconds. The only scene

Comment: if you are writting an external file,then the crash wouldnt affect the file.Just write into a file,eg txt,then before writing it again,read the current content,append the new content and rewrite your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your App is critical, I would look into setting up a DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler by calling `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` in your Application class. This way in the handler, you can write all unsaved data, AND you can restart the app for continued handling of your critical data. I would put some seconds counter in there, to prevent an infinite loop of crashes. The Open Source ACRA library uses `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, so you may get some idea from there on how to use it.
An additional idea is to write the data using a service in a separate process, search for "Remote Service". This way, even if the app crashes, the service will still be alive. You will have to setup some functionality on how to share the data between the app and the service. If the app is really critical, I would setup 2 remote services, one that gets the info from the sensor (and caches it as a backup until confirmed that it's written), and one that caches the data and writes it every few seconds. Each service should also have a DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler as above. This is in addition to the actual app, that will have the user interface. Though it is a little waste of resources, but for critical data it is not wasted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to study the reason of your app crash. If your app is crashing because of internal exceptions there is a better way of dealing with this thing.

Write a good exception management and use this blocks to write data to internal memory whenever there is an exception generated. Re-start the app after the data has been successfully written.

It you app is crashing because of external reasons and you are unable to catch exceptions, you have to think of some other way.

Answer (score 0):

i donot think there's a good method. What more important is to avoid crash maybe

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to a file every 5 ms, which will be a costly operation, you can save data to SharedPreferences every 5 ms and every 2 sec, save the data from SharedPreferences to a file. SharedPreferences content won't be deleted even if app crashes and hence you will not have any data loss.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea. I have read multiple different posts suggesting against this. SharedPreferences should not be used for frequent updates. It should only be used to store less frequently updated small pieces of information.